# Send foreign key objects with all child or children objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there any way to always retrieve parent objects with the child or children object for a rails API only application ?

e.g. I have a @students array. Each student object in @students array has two foreign keys as standard_id and school_id. Now all the objects have by default standard_id and school_id. Instead I want standard object and school object in each student object in the @students array.

The response which I get

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "standard_id": 1,
    "school_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-04-14T11:36:03.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-14T11:36:03.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "standard_id": 1,
    "school_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-04-14T11:41:38.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-14T11:41:45.000Z"
  }
]
```

The response which I want

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "standard_id": 1,
    "school_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-04-14T11:36:03.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-14T11:36:03.000Z",
    "standard": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "1",
      "created_at": "2019-04-14T11:32:15.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-04-14T11:32:15.000Z"
    },
    "school": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "SACS",
      "created_at": "2019-04-14T11:35:24.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-04-14T11:35:24.000Z"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "standard_id": 1,
    "school_id": 1,
    "created_at": "2019-04-14T11:41:38.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2019-04-14T11:41:45.000Z",
    "standard": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "1",
      "created_at": "2019-04-14T11:32:15.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-04-14T11:32:15.000Z"
    },
    "school": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "SACS",
      "created_at": "2019-04-14T11:35:24.000Z",
      "updated_at": "2019-04-14T11:35:24.000Z"
    }
  }
]
```

**Is there any common solution for all controllers ? Because the application is already built. Its very hectic now to format data manually in every controller. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: are you using any serializer? or the response is directly sent from the controller as `render json:`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Rails default's `as_json` serializer in your controller, i.e. see below:

```
render json: @students
# ^ above will default call `.to_json` to `@students`, which will also call `.as_json`
# thereby, equivalently calling:
# render json: @students.as_json
```

...then, you can modify `as_json` a bit ([see docs](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON/as_json)), so that the JSON will include the first-level nested associations; see below

### Solution

**app/models/student.rb**

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :standard
  belongs_to :school

  def as_json(**options)
    unless options.has_key? :include
      options.merge!(include: [:standard, :school])
    end
    super(options)
  end

  # or if you don't want to manually include "each" association, and just dynamically include per association
  # def as_json(**options)
  #   unless options.has_key? :include
  #     options.merge!(
  #       include: self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name)
  #     )
  #   end
  #   super(options)
  # end
end
```

### Global Solution (Rails >= 5)

same as Solution above, but if you want this to work for **ALL** models and not just for `Student` model, then the following:

**app/models/application_record.rb**

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  def as_json(**options)
    unless options.has_key? :include
      options.merge!(
        include: self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name)
      )
    end
    super(options)
  end
end
```

#### Usage Example

```
# rails console
students = Student.all
puts students.as_json
# => [{"id"=>1, "standard_id"=>1, "school_id"=>1, "created_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:36:03.000Z", "updated_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:36:03.000Z", "standard"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"1", "created_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:32:15.000Z", "updated_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:32:15.000Z"}, "school"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"SACS", "created_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:35:24.000Z", "updated_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:35:24.000Z"}}, {"id"=>2, "standard_id"=>1, "school_id"=>1, "created_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:41:38.000Z", "updated_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:41:45.000Z", "standard"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"1", "created_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:32:15.000Z", "updated_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:32:15.000Z"}, "school"=>{"id"=>1, "name"=>"SACS", "created_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:35:24.000Z", "updated_at"=>"2019-04-14T11:35:24.000Z"}}]
```

*Solutions above only renders the first-level associations as part of the JSON response, it will not "deep" render the second-level nor third-level, etc... associations.*

### Updated (With Pagination):

I got curious with your extended request to integrate pagination; hence my possible solution (tested working, though not sure yet if there are side-effects) below:

You'll need a "pagination" gem, i.e. in my example below I'm using [kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari)

**app/models/application_record.rb**

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true

  def as_json(**options)
    unless options.has_key? :include
      options.merge!(
        include: self.class.reflect_on_all_associations.map(&:name).inject({}) do |hash, name|
          paginate = options.dig(:association_paginations, name.to_sym, :paginate)
          paginate = true if paginate.nil?
          page = options.dig(:association_paginations, name.to_sym, :page) || 1
          per = options.dig(:association_paginations, name.to_sym, :per) || Kaminari.config.default_per_page

          hash[name.to_sym] = {
            paginate: paginate,
            page: page,
            per: per
          }
          hash
        end
      )
    end
    super(options)
  end
end
```

**app/config/initializers/active_model_serialization_patch.rb**

```
module ActiveModel::Serialization
  private def serializable_add_includes(options = {})
    if Gem.loaded_specs['activemodel'].version.to_s != '6.0.0.beta3' # '5.2.3'
      raise "Version mismatch! \
        Not guaranteed to work properly without side effects! \
        You'll have to copy and paste (and modify) to below correct code (and Gem version!) from \
        https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/serialization.rb#L178"
    else
      # copied code: start
      return unless includes = options[:include]

      unless includes.is_a?(Hash)
        includes = Hash[Array(includes).flat_map { |n| n.is_a?(Hash) ? n.to_a : [[n, {}]] }]
      end

      includes.each do |association, opts|
        if opts[:paginate]
          opts[:page] ||= 1
          opts[:per] ||= Kaminari.config.default_per_page
          records = send(association).page(opts[:page]).per(opts[:per])
        else
          records = send(association)
        end

        if records
          yield association, records, opts
        end
      end
      # copied code: end
    end
  end
end
```

**app/config/initializers/active_record_relation_patch.rb**

```
class ActiveRecord::Relation
  def as_json(**options)
    if options[:paginate]
      options[:page] ||= 1
      options[:per] ||= Kaminari.config.default_per_page
      options[:paginate] = false
      page(options[:page]).per(options[:per]).as_json(options)
    else
      super(options)
    end
  end
end
```

**your_controller.rb**

```
def some_action
  @students = Student.all

  render json: @students.as_json(
    paginate: true,
    page: params[:page],
    per: params[:per],
    association_paginations: params[:association_paginations]
  )
end
```

#### Example Request 1

```
http://localhost:3000/your_controller/some_action?per=2&page=1
```

#### Example Response 1

only two students returned because `per` = 2

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    school_id: 101,
    school: { id: 101, ... },
    standard_id: 201,
    standard: { id: 201, ... },
    subjects: [
      { id: 301, ... },
      { id: 302, ... },
      { id: 303, ... },
      { id: 304, ... },
      { id: 305, ... },
      ...
    ],
    attendances: [
      { id: 123, ... },
      { id: 124, ... },
      { id: 125, ... },
      { id: 126, ... },
      { id: 127, ... },
      { id: 128, ... },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    ...
  }
]
```

#### Example Request 2

```
http://localhost:3000/your_controller/some_action?per=2&page=1&association_paginations[subjects][per]=2
```

#### Example Response 2

only two students returned because `per` = 2

only two subjects returned because `association_paginations[subjects][per]` = 2

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    school_id: 101,
    school: { id: 101, ... },
    standard_id: 201,
    standard: { id: 201, ... },
    subjects: [
      { id: 301, ... },
      { id: 302, ... },
    ],
    attendances: [
      { id: 123, ... },
      { id: 124, ... },
      { id: 125, ... },
      { id: 126, ... },
      { id: 127, ... },
      { id: 128, ... },
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    ...
  }
]
```

*P.S. because solution above involves monkey-patching, I will recommend using  [ActiveModelSerializers::Model](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/tree/0-10-stable#high-level-behavior) instead because your requested feature is now getting complex.*

Comment: `self.class.reflect_on_all_associations` above will return an array of all the associations defined on that model (this includes `:has_many`, `:has_one`, and `:belongs_to`). I have a feeling that perhaps you just need to include them into the JSON only if they are `:belongs_to` association; if this is the case then just use the following instead: `self.class.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to)`

Comment: thanks a lot. The solution works just fine and is a life saver. Thank you so much. But the problem right now arises is for has_many associations. Is it possible to limit data for pagination implementation since I do not want to make the api call heavy in case we have million data in has_many associations.

Comment: @BibekDas see my updated answer. Hope it works for you.